# 15.04 WiFi on Dell D630

Tags: networking, wireless, 15.04

No WiFi on Dell Latitude D630. Just Installed 15.04. Window user so no idea how to proceed. I assume I need a driver but do not know how figure what adapter I have or how to get a driver (new to Ubuntu & Linux). TY

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

To find the adapter, run this command.

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lshw -c ne
```

If you're using Broadcom, here's a great resource that will show you how to install the drivers (I had to do this when I installed 15.04 last weekend)

http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/install-broadcom-sta-wireless-driver-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04/

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried to install STA, B43 & B43-Legacy. None seemed to do the trick. My system never does shut down, I have to hold power button. Not sure if this is significant. Ideas?

Comment: The 'lspci' shows I have "BCM4311". TY

Comment: That's interesting... that did the trick for me but my device is showing BCM4322. I did find an article elsewhere on this site that might help http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Comment: Basically the gist of it is, that you'll need to uninstall the drivers in the one article, run some updates (to reflect the purge and to update the pcids), and then install package linux-firmware-nonfree.